# Access columns of data frame in user defined function using apply

Tags: r, apply

I am trying to understand how to use user defined function in R using apply. I just can't seem to figure out how I can access the columns in my data frame when inside the function. For example:

```
letter <- c("A", "B", "C")
df <- as.data.frame(letter)

my_fun <- function(x) {
  print(LETTER)
}

apply(df, 1, my_fun)
```

Where it say's `LETTER` I would like to print the actual value of that row's letter column. How is this done in R?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. You pass `x` to the function and `print` `LETTER`. How is `LETTER` and `x` related?

Comment: @RonakShah that is correct. That is exactly what I point out in my last sentence. I would like it to be substituted for the column value of letter in the row represented by x.

Comment: You can just do `print(x)` instead of `print(LETTER)` in the function. If not, can you show your expected output ?

Comment: @RonakShah I figured out I can access the value using x['letter'], maybe should had given an expected output example. I thought I made myself clear enough but I guess not. Will post the answer soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm going to assume that x is an arguement in your function for which letter to choose. to print the character vector position try:

```
print(as.character(letter))
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more trail and error I found out I can access the content of a column as folllows:

```
letter <- c("A", "B", "C")
df <- as.data.frame(letter)

my_fun <- function(x) {
  print(x['letter'])
}

apply(df, 1, my_fun)
```

Leaving this as a reference to future me or other that describe this issue the same as I did in a search engine.